# DBRichEdit RTF encoding lost transitioning application from BDE to DBX

Tags: delphi, richedit, bde, dbx

My team is converting a BDE application to DBX using D2007.

A TTable has been replaced with a TSQLDataSet/TDataSetProvider/TClientDataSet combination.

A TStringField has been used to access the RTF in the Oracle varchar field via a TDBRichedit component.

The BDE version transmitted the RTF encoding to the db just fine. For some reason the RTF encoding gets stripped in the dbx version?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have two ideas, but I'm not sure if anyone of this might help.

The first one is to check the PlainText property of your DBRichEdit. Make sure it is set to false.

The second idea is to use a BLOB-Field instead of a Varchar-Field. No component should touch the content of that.

regards

Comment: Actually I added a long column to the Oracle table and copied the varchar column into it. Then attached the TDBRichEdit to that and it worked. I guess the BDE interpreted varchars longer than 256 as memos but dbx only sees varchars (no matter how long) as strings.